# I don t understand this for loop

Tags: python

```
def available_moves(self):
    moves = []
    for (i, spot) in enumerate(self.board):
        if spot == ' ':
            moves.append(i)
    return moves
```

I am making a python tic tac toe project from a tutorial but I don t understand the for loop I don t get what for (i, spot) means

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `enumerate`?   Have you tried searching for "Python enumerate" in your favorite search engine?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What don't you understand about it? What do you hope we can tell you? Did you try to figure out how the loop works, for example by checking the values of `i` and `spot` each time through the loop? If so, what did you discover this way? Did you try to look up and follow a tutorial? Did you try to check the documentation for the `enumerate` function?

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
for (i, spot) in enumerate(self.board):
```

loops through the items in board and given you each items index along with the item.

Specifically, `i` here refers to the position in the collection of the current element, with `spot` being the current element from the `board` collection.